# DRF prefetch related still causing N+1 queries

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Models:

```
class GradePolicy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    minScore = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, db_column="minscore")
    maxScore = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, default=100, db_column="maxscore")
    policyChoices = (
        ('Numerical', 'Numerical'),
        ('Textual', 'Textual')
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Textual', choices=policyChoices)


class GradeLevel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    policy = models.ForeignKey(GradePolicy, null=True, blank=True,
                           on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Views:

```
class GradePolicyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Retrieve grade policies
    """
    queryset = GradePolicy.objects.prefetch_related('gradelevel_set').order_by('pk')
    serializer_class = GradePolicySerializer

class GradeLevelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GradeLevel.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    serializer_class = GradeLevelSerializer
```

Serializers:

```
class GradeLevelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="gbook:gradelevels-detail")
    policy = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GradeLevel
        fields = ['pk', 'url', 'name', 'score', 'abbreviation', 'policy']


class GradePolicySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="gbook:gradepolicies-detail")
    levels = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_levels(self, obj):
        policy: GradePolicy = obj
        levels = policy.gradelevel_set.prefetch_related('policy').order_by("-score").all()
        return GradeLevelSerializer(levels, many=True, context={'request': None}).data

    class Meta:
        model = GradePolicy
        fields = ['pk', 'url', 'name', 'minScore', 'maxScore', 'type', 'levels']
```

I'm getting reports from Sentry that calling `/gradepolicies`, which is the `list` endpoint for `GradePolicy`, is causing N+1 queries. Looking at the queries, that does seem to be the case:

```
(0.004) SELECT "gbook_gradepolicy"."id", "gbook_gradepolicy"."name", "gbook_gradepolicy"."minscore", "gbook_gradepolicy"."maxscore", "gbook_gradepolicy"."type" FROM "gbook_gradepolicy" ORDER BY "gbook_gradepolicy"."id" ASC; args=()

(0.005) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 2 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(2,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 3 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(3,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 4 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(4,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 5 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(5,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 6 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(6,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 7 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(7,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 8 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(8,)
```

To prevent this, I'm prefetching as shown in the code above. The result of that is:

```
(0.002) SELECT "gbook_gradepolicy"."id", "gbook_gradepolicy"."name", "gbook_gradepolicy"."minscore", "gbook_gradepolicy"."maxscore", "gbook_gradepolicy"."type" FROM "gbook_gradepolicy" ORDER BY "gbook_gradepolicy"."id" ASC; args=()

(0.004) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8); args=(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 2 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(2,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 3 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(3,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 4 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(4,)

(0.000) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 5 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(5,)

(0.001) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 6 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(6,)

(0.000) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 7 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(7,)

(0.000) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" = 8 ORDER BY "gbook_gradelevel"."score" DESC; args=(8,)
```

I see in there what looks like the result of the prefetch (`(0.004) SELECT "gbook_gradelevel"."id", "gbook_gradelevel"."name", "gbook_gradelevel"."score", "gbook_gradelevel"."abbreviation", "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" FROM "gbook_gradelevel" WHERE "gbook_gradelevel"."policy_id" IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8); args=(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`, but it still performs all of the extra queries below.

How can I get rid of the N+1 query issue with this lookup?

Comment: Why are you using `prefetch_related` when you can use `select_related` ?

Comment: In which spot? There are two

Comment: I believe the issue is in `get_levels` method. You don't have to call the queryset for each instance of `GradePolicy`

Comment: I think that you're correct about the cause of the extra queries, but I wasn't able to get the levels attached to the serializer any other way. Is there another path?

Comment: Have you replaced `levels = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` to  `levels = GradeLevelSerializer(many=True)` and remove `get_levels` method

Comment: If I make that replacement, I get ```Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `levels` on serializer `GradePolicySerializer`.The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `GradePolicy` instance. Original exception text was: 'GradePolicy' object has no attribute 'levels'.``` The fact that there's no `levels` field on the policy object was the reason I added the getter method

Comment: This works, though! ```gradelevel_set = GradeLevelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GradePolicy
        fields = ['pk', 'url', 'name', 'minScore', 'maxScore', 'type', 'gradelevel_set']```

Comment: Oh sorry my bad `prefetch_related` is fine as you are doing reverse foreign key relationship in viewset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `get_levels` method that is slowing down your API. You don't need it just replace it with your `GradeLevelSerializer` like this:

```
class GradePolicySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="gbook:gradepolicies-detail")
    levels = GradeLevelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GradePolicy
        fields = ['pk', 'url', 'name', 'minScore', 'maxScore', 'type', 'levels']
```

The `prefetch_related` is fine in viewset as you are doing reverse relationship.

You can specify the ordering on score as well in your viewset using [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)

By default DRF doesn't optimize the database hits for more take a look [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

You can also update [related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) name of your reverse relationship like this:

```
class GradeLevel(models.Model):
  ...
  policy = models.ForeignKey(GradePolicy, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='levels')
```

Comment: This almost works. You have to add `source` parameter: `levels = GradeLevelSerializer(source='gradelevel_set', many=True)`. With that change, I'll accept this answer - thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you test how many queries are happening now ? And how much performance improvement you have achieved ?

Comment: The extra queries are definitely gone now. The performace hasn't changed all that much. I have a few much larger queries in production that I'm going to apply this to that will hopefully show some performance gains.

Comment: Yes! In production, same query from this morning to today: 39.2s, 34.8s -> 2.23s, 2.71s

Comment: You mean now because of removing `get_levels` change it is taking 2 seconds instead of 39 seconds right ?

Comment: It's actually a different query, the prefetch on two levels of nesting did it